# Using SwiftMailer before a redirect

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, bolt-cms

I have an issue regarding the use of SwiftMailer before a redirect. If I allow the controller making the request to return then emails are sent fine. For example:

```
function foo() {

    // ...

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom($sender)
        ->setTo($recipient)
        ->setBody(strip_tags($html))
        ->addPart($html, 'text/html');
    $result = $this->app['mailer']->send($message);

    return '';
}
```

The above works so long as I return a non-null response.

However if I do the same but with a redirect like this:

```
function foo() {

    // ... 

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom($sender)
        ->setTo($recipient)
        ->setBody(strip_tags($html))
        ->addPart($html, 'text/html');
    $result = $this->app['mailer']->send($message);

    simpleredirect($this->app['paths']['root']);
}
```

Then the message is not sent.

Note: the `simpleredirect()` function terminates the script, as is standard practice.

In both examples the `$result` comes back as the number of specified recipients. Therefore I can only assume that the mail is queued and some kind of dispatch runs on a conventional return which is missed out in the presence of a redirect.

I have a feeling that the [SwiftMailer `spool`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html) option might be enabled. However doing a few searches of my Bolt projects I cannot seem to find it being set anywhere. If spooling is enabled then the email won't be sent until the kernal termination phase, which the redirect (having `die` will avoid).

Comment: Put a `return` before `simpleredirect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found how to do it:

```
$app['swiftmailer.spooltransport']->getSpool()->flushQueue($app['swiftmailer.transport']);
```

By adding this line before the redirect it makes the kernal send the email.

Here is the reason:

> The Swiftmailer provider sends the emails using the
>   `KernelEvents::TERMINATE` event, which is fired after the response has
>   been sent. However, as this event isn't fired for console commands,
>   your emails won't be sent.

Comment: The official recommended way for doing it is to execute a console command - http://symfony.com/doc/3.2/console/command_in_controller.html

Answer (score 0):

Put a `return` before `simpleredirect`. This is required as every controller action must return `Response` object.

In case of `return ''`, Symfony itself create `Response` object.

Comment: That won't work because `simpleredirect` has a `die()` command.

Comment: Then you should mention it in your question. Anyways, add `simpleredirect` code & then I can help further.

Comment: I thought it would be pretty obvious, as that's how redirects generally work. They usually terminate as no output is required after them.